# Upgrade report shows Invalid permissions will trigger runtime exceptions

Tags: 10

Preparing my Drupal 9.5.1 website to go on Drupal 10. I have installed module Upgrade status.

getting in report this kind of error :

Invalid permissions will trigger runtime exceptions in Drupal 10. Permissions should be defined in a permissions.yml file or a permission callback.

most of the permissions is for background image module, Paragraphs, Flag.

I've found closest answer for this. Like a patch to be applied https://www.drupal.org/project/layout_builder_styles/issues/3323459

https://www.drupal.org/project/upgrade_status/issues/3223068

but it won't solve this for me...

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Have you already updated to the latest version for those modules?

Comment: @NoSssweat at the moment i have 22 modules are not compatible with d10 but 80 of them and my custom modules are prepared for the migration. in Upgrade status module report in Requirements table i see that permission error... and i don't getting how to solve this

Comment: Paragraphs, flag, and Background image are compatible and have latest version @NoSssweat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching trough the Drupal.org Upgrade Status module issues i got [some kind of answer to my question](https://www.drupal.org/project/upgrade_status/issues/3265426)

where maintainers discussed this kind of the message on D9.3 environment as per their discussion :

> Otherwise, the user may think they should be doing something to fix the issue when in fact it will get fixed. Perhaps add:
> This problem may be automatically corrected by the upgrade to Drupal 9.3.

So i assume that perfectly suits and to the D9.5.2